# Angular cli build prod: TypeError: Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined issue

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

[Click here to see the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aeuhj.png)
    {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.19",
        "@angular/cli": "~8.3.19",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.14",
        "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.14",
        "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
        "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
        "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
        "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
        "karma": "~4.1.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
        "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
        "protractor": "~5.4.0",
        "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
        "tslint": "~5.15.0",
        "typescript": "~3.5.3",
        "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.6.0"
      }

Comment: Update your question please. No one cant understand

Comment: @Tony Ngo Pls check in the error message

Comment: Just restart the application i.e. `ng serve` and see if it still persists.

Comment: @Arcteezy i have done as you said but still facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

I think is your `typescript` version 3.5.3 update to 3.7.0

Comment: I updated 3.5.3 to  3.7.2 but i have faced the below issue 
ERROR in The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=3.4.0 and <3.6.0 but 3.7.2 w
as found instead.

Comment: No facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

i fixed the issue by reducing the budget value in the angular.json file. Thanks for the help!